# Stuck in math showing relationship between poisson and exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Given that

$X \sim \operatorname{exponential}(1)$

$\operatorname{Pr}(X>s+t \mid X>s)=\operatorname{Pr}(X>t)$

$Z_k$ denotes the waiting time for k successive events and $Z_k \sim \operatorname{gamma}(k,1)$.

We are asked to prove that the number of events that occur in a particular time $t$ follows poisson distribution.

The solution provided goes as follows:

Let $X \sim \operatorname{exponential}(1)$ be the waiting time for the $(k+1)^{th}$ event.

$\operatorname{Pr}($ exactly $k$ events occur in time $t)= \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k} \leqslant t, Z_{k+1} \gt t\right) = 
\int_{0}^{t} \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k}=z\right) \operatorname{Pr}(X>t-z) d z$

I can't understand how the integral equation follows from the previous equation mathematically. How can I use laws of probability to get to the integral equation?

Comment: You don't use Bayes' rule.  It is the law of total probability ... plus extra steps.

Comment: See this text using different ways to express conditional densities : https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/04%3A_Conditional_Probability/4.02%3A_Continuous_Conditional_Probability

Answer (score 2):

We want the probability that the next arrival occurs after time $t$, given that it occurs *after* an arrival that occurs at time $z$ .

$$\begin{align}\Pr(Z_{k+1}>t\mid Z_k=z)&=\Pr(X>t\mid X>z)\\[1ex]&=\Pr(X>t-z+z\mid X>z)\\[1ex]&=\Pr(X>t-z)\end{align}$$

---

Thus $$\begin{align}\Pr(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_k\leqslant t)&=\int_0^t f_{Z_k}(z)\,\Pr(Z_{k+1}>t\mid Z_k=t)\,\mathrm dz\\[1ex]&=\int_0^t f_{Z_k}(z)\,\Pr(X>t-z)\,\mathrm dz \end{align}$$

Comment: Note $\Pr(Z_k=z)$ is nonsensical, as we require a probability density function.

Comment: I purposely have $Z_k \leq t$ , its not by mistake..

Comment: Isnt $\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) = \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t | Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) * \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) $ ? Where does the integral come from? Don't I need to introduce a 3rd variable like $z$ as $\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_{k} \leqslant t, Z_k = z\right)$ to get the integral?

Comment: Like $\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) = \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t | Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) * \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k} \leqslant t\right)  = \int_{0}^{t}\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_{k} \leqslant t, Z_k = z\right) dz$ ?

Comment: The integral is the law of total probability. When $B$ is continuously distributed with positive real support for its probability density function $f_B$, then $$\small{\Pr(A\in D, B\leq t)={\int_0^t f_B(z)\,\Pr(A\in D\mid B=z)\,\mathrm dz}}$$

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing.. $\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t, Z_{k} \leqslant t\right)=\operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t \mid Z_{k} \leqslant t\right) * \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k} \leqslant t\right)= \int_{0}^{t} \operatorname{Pr}\left(Z_{k+1}>t | Z_{k}=z\right) * f_{Z_k}(z) dz $ My doubt is how can you pull the conditional term in the integral? and how can you replace the $Z_k \leq t$ with $=$ in the same term?

Comment: Since the integral is the expansion of $Pr(Z_k \leq t)$ .. that's why can't understand how you included the conditional term in the integration and also changed the leq to eq. Will be super grateful if you clarified it for me! thanks..

Comment: Consider that if you were dealing with a natural number valued, discrete random variable, then: $$\small\begin{align}&\Pr(A\in D, B\in\{0,1,...,t\})\\[1ex]=&\sum_{z=0}^t \Pr(A\in D, B=z)\\[1ex]=&\sum_{z=0}^t \Pr(B=z)\,\Pr(A\in D\mid B=z)\end{align}$$